# Spinner items are having no effect on click !!!, the list just remains on the screen

Tags: android, android-spinner, onitemclicklistener

I have an activity which takes in the bank names and the account number from the user. The bank name and the corresponding account number are stored in the database. Now there are two spinners in another activity , one of them  gets the bank names and populates itself with them, the other one gets the account number corresponding to that bank. I am successful in populating the spinners.The only problem I am having is that, the entries in the first spinner(holding the bank names) are not clickable, and so the second spinner becomes useless as well.I am not able to understand as what could be the reason for it. Here is the code for the spinners :

```
   // in onCreate() function
   // for the spinner holding bank name
    Cursor cursor = myDatabase.getData();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    myAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(AddTransaction.this,
                R.layout.spinnerlayout, cursor,
                new String[] { DatabaseClass.KEY_BANK_NAME_ID },
                new int[] { R.id.bankName },
                SimpleCursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
    mySpinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    get_datafrom_spinner = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(DatabaseClass.KEY_BANK_NAME_ID));
        // Toast.makeText(AddTransaction.this, get_datafrom_spinner,
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    myDatabase.close();



@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        myDatabase.open();

        int pos = position;
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) myAdapter.getItem(pos);
        bank_name = cursor.getString(cursor // name of the bank
                                            // selected
                .getColumnIndex(DatabaseClass.KEY_BANK_NAME_ID));
        myAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(AddTransaction.this,
                R.layout.spinnerlayout, cursor,
                new String[] { DatabaseClass.KEY_BANK_NAME_ID, },
                new int[] { R.id.bankName },
                SimpleCursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
        mySpinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        // Toast.makeText(AddTransaction.this, s,
        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // returns the account numbers corresponding to this bank name
        Cursor c = myDatabase.getAccountData(bank_name);
        c.moveToFirst();

        myAdapter_for_account = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                AddTransaction.this, R.layout.account_number_spinner, c,
                new String[] { DatabaseClass.KEY_ACCOUNT_NUMBER_ID },
                new int[] { R.id.accNum },
                SimpleCursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);

        mySpinner_for_account.setAdapter(myAdapter_for_account);

        // position of the the clicked in the spinner for account
        int position_account = mySpinner_for_account
                .getSelectedItemPosition();

        Cursor cursor2 = (Cursor) myAdapter_for_account
                .getItem(position_account);

        // holds the account number for the spinner item selected
        account_number_selected = cursor2.getString(cursor2
                .getColumnIndex(DatabaseClass.KEY_ACCOUNT_NUMBER_ID));

        // Toast.makeText(AddTransaction.this, account_number_selected,
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Cursor balance = myDatabase
                .getAmountfor_Account(account_number_selected);
        balance.moveToFirst();

        /*
         * c = myDatabase.getAmountfor_Account(account_for_spiiner_account);
         * c.moveToFirst();
         */

        // get the balance as a string

        balance_in_account = balance.getString(balance // <--
                .getColumnIndex(DatabaseClass.KEY_CURRENT_BALANCE_ID));

        // Toast.makeText(AddTransaction.this, balance_in_account,
        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    myDatabase.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_id);
s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView adapter, View v, int i, long lng) {
//do something here
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView arg0) {
//do something else
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working, the problem was I was declaring the two spinner in the same onItemSelected() function, each spinner should have its own onItemSelected function to work.